# how to let every user see her own data when he login to member panel?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created my own web application with php and mysql, it is an application which you can practice english in it, an user can register and login to use features that provide to him my application but when user connect to member panel he can store data but problem is every user can display the same data that other users had stored in database.
I have one database and two tables:
table for users and table for data but the problem is i don't want all users see the same data.
how to let every user see her own data when he login to member panel?

Comment: Google multitenancy in PHP

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yeah, that one. Typo fail.

Comment: This is a multi-tenant application and it requires adding the appropriate `WHERE` conditions to each query.

Answer (score 1):

If data is unique for each user, better add a user email or user unique id in data table as well. Then use sessions to store the user id that has logged in successfully and query the database with that unique id.

Alternatively, if you have data in levels like for beginners, intermediate and advanced users you need to add a new column in users and data table that can identify the level of data and which user is accessing it.

Please update your database schema and normalise it. Probably your problem will be solved with a good database design.